# How to query SOLR for empty fields?

Tags: solr, lucene

I have a large solr index, and I have noticed some fields are not updated correctly (the index is dynamic).

This has resulted in some fields having an empty "id" field.

I have tried these queries, but they didn't work:

```
 id:''
 id:NULL
 id:null
 id:""
 id:
 id:['' TO *]
```

Is there a way to query empty fields?

Thanks

Answer (score 161, accepted):

Try this:

```
?q=-id:["" TO *]
```

Comment: Even though the SolrQuerySyntax page says -id:[* TO *], only -id:["" TO *] worked for me on solr 1.4.

Comment: @user2043553 Nope, if you `?q=-id:*` you get `Cannot parse '-q:*': '*' or '?' not allowed as first character in WildcardQuery`

Comment: @YzmirRamirez I've tried with the example of Solr 4.5.1 and `?q=-id:*` seems to work as expected. Maybe the parsing error is related to this [issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15979/wildcardquery-error-in-solr).

Comment: Sorry, forgot the version ... `Lucene Specification Version: 3.2.0` I was using.  Glad they added the syntax in Solr 4.5.1.

Comment: Beware that this syntax seems to also return rows whose field value starts with a whitespace (in Solr 4.3)

Answer (score 133):

One caveat! If you want to compose this via OR or AND you cannot use it in this form:

```
-myfield:*
```

but you must use

```
(*:* NOT myfield:*)
```

This form is perfectly composable. Apparently SOLR will expand the first form to the second, but only when it is a top node. Hope this saves you some time!

Comment: This answer deserves more points than it actually has. You saved us a lot of time!

Comment: +1 here as well. I implemented the other options but I had to include it in an fq= rather than q= and also had to implement an OR to check if the field was empty OR had a specific value. This is the only option that worked for that use case.

Comment: I agree this should be the accepted answer on the question

Comment: You saved me so much of a headache. I'm not sure thank you is sufficient.

Comment: I also had to use `fq`, with `q = *:*`. Also note you obviously can't do this check against non-indexed/only-stored fields which caught me out for a second.

Answer (score 71):

According to [SolrQuerySyntax](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrQuerySyntax), you can use `q=-id:[* TO *]`.

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10722145/solr-how-do-i-construct-a-query-that-requires-a-not-null-location-field

Answer (score 13):

If you have a large index, you should use a default value

```
   <field ... default="EMPTY" />
```

and then query for this default value.
This is much more efficient than q=-id:["" TO *]

Comment: Would this only work for fields of type String?   How would you do it for for boolean?

Comment: I guess, it should work in the same way. But I have never checked it.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use it like this.

```
fq=!id:['' TO *]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SolrSharp, it does not support negative queries.

You need to change QueryParameter.cs (Create a new parameter)

```
private bool _negativeQuery = false;

public QueryParameter(string field, string value, ParameterJoin parameterJoin = ParameterJoin.AND, bool negativeQuery = false)
{
    this._field = field;
    this._value = value.Trim();
    this._parameterJoin = parameterJoin;
    this._negativeQuery = negativeQuery;
}

public bool NegativeQuery
{
    get { return _negativeQuery; }
    set { _negativeQuery = value; }
}
```

And in QueryParameterCollection.cs class, the ToString() override, looks if the Negative parameter is true

```
arQ[x] = (qp.NegativeQuery ? "-(" : "(") + qp.ToString() + ")" + (qp.Boost != 1 ? "^" + qp.Boost.ToString() : "");
```

When you call the parameter creator, if it's a negative value. Simple change the propertie

```
List<QueryParameter> QueryParameters = new List<QueryParameter>();
QueryParameters.Add(new QueryParameter("PartnerList", "[* TO *]", ParameterJoin.AND, true));
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it with filter query
q=*:*&fq=-id:*

Answer (score 1):

A note added here, to make the field searchable first, it needs the field type in SOLR schema set to "indexed = true". Then you can use "`field_name:*`" for string type and "`field_name:[* TO *]`" for numeric type.