# Solr - How do I construct a query that requires a NOT NULL Location field

Tags: solr, geospatial, solr-query-syntax

I have a Solr index with a set of coordinates stored as a `Location` type; I would like to query for documents where this field has a non-null value.

What is the query syntax to perform the NOT NULL check on a Location field?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The canonical way is this:

```
fieldName:[* TO *]
```

Using a `''` on the left side as Paige Cook suggested will probably work too but I don't trust it as much as I do the above.  And since this is to a Location field, you will probably have to do this against one of the two underlying actual fields versus this logical composite field.  They start with `fieldName` and end with some sort of numeric suffix; look in the Schema Browser to see what the actual name is.

An important thing to be aware of here is that a query like this is expensive for Solr to do as it much do a full index scan on this field.  If you have many distinct location field values (thousands on up?), then this is a big deal.  If you do this in a filter query, then it will be cached and it's perhaps moot.  If you want this query to run fast, then at index time you should index a boolean field to indicate if there is a value in this field or not.

Comment: Thanks David, the [* TO *] syntax, combined with checking both backing fields, appears to work correctly (e.g. `field_0_coord:[* TO *] AND field_1_coord:[* TO *]`).  Thanks for the performance tip as well!

Comment: You don't have to do this against both coord fields, which is twice as slow, just one.  If one has a value, the other does, and vice versa.

Comment: Because I just came across this "solution" in our project: Don't use this for a String field.

Comment: @DavidSmiley I can also use fieldName:(*) to achieve NOT NULL values for field. Can you please say if is there any performance impact difference between these 2 queries 
 [* TO *] and (*)

Comment: @ChiragShah your syntax confused the StackOverflow formatting but I assume you are asking if `field:[* TO *]` is equivalent to `field:*`.  I think these are the same as of Jan 2020.

Answer (score 13):

You can add this to your query `fieldname:['' TO *]`. This will be the equivalent of a NOT NULL check.

I got this from the post - [Solr - Field Not Null Searches](http://melikedev.com/2010/07/27/solr-field-not-null-searches/)

Comment: Thanks Paige, but unfortunately that doesn't appear to work for the `Location`

Comment: to expand a bit more, the field as well as the backing fields are numeric; evaluating them against `''` results in a NumberFormatException

Comment: Sorry that I missed that this was numeric. David Smiley has the correct answer.

Answer (score 7):

For a location field (solr.LatLonType), use the following filter query: `-fieldName:[-90,-180 TO 90,180]` (the coordinates outside this range are still invalid)

Answer (score -7):

Try this `q= !fieldname:NULL` this will be equivalent to `Fieldvalue` is NOT NULL.

Asked by STW
I have a Solr index with a set of coordinates stored as a Location type; I would like to query for documents where this field has a non-null value.

What is the query syntax to perform the NOT NULL check on a Location field?

Comment: The query `!fieldname:NULL` isn't working, shows the error 400:
java.text.ParseException: missing parens: NULL