# How do I search for a lucene index where a particular field does not exist?

Tags: java, lucene

I need to search for items where a lucene field does not exist. How do I do that ?

Comment: do you have some code to share?

Comment: I am using plain java code.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible with Lucene but if using SOLR is an option for you try this answer: [How to query SOLR for empty fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4240008/789729)