# How to find a SOLR entry that has a field with no value?

Tags: solr

I have a local SOLR server with some entries that have a field  `"debaTest": ""` while some entries don't have this field at all.

Is there a way in Solr to filter out the entries that have this field? the value for the field will always be null or empty.

*Please note:* Something in the lines of `q=-debaTest:[* TO *]` or 
`-debaTest:*` won't work for my requirement as this returns the entries that don't have these fields at all and I want the entries that have this field but without a value.

Comment: `q=debaTest:""`. Have you tried this?

Comment: Yes. This does not work as well.

Comment: There was a typo there, I meant `q=-dbatest:""`. Is that what you tried?

Comment: My guess is since it shows up in a query like `q=-debaTest:*` it thinks the field does not exist at all. If that's true i would say that's a flawed way of looking at thinks. I would be happy if someone says this assumption is wrong and we can indeed lookup the field :)

Comment: `q=-dbatest:""` doesn't work as well

Comment: Here's another so post that could help you. https://stackoverflow.com/q/4238609/1822643

Comment: Didn't help. Same outcome. I have tried these before.