# unexpected docvalues type NONE for field 'location_0_coordinate' (expected one of [BINARY, NUMERIC, SORTED, SORTED_NUMERIC, SORTED_SET])

Tags: solr, solarium

Recently I started getting this error on solr

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: unexpected docvalues type NONE for field 'location_0_coordinate' (expected one of [BINARY, NUMERIC, SORTED, SORTED_NUMERIC, SORTED_SET]). Re-index with correct docvalues type

I have a `location` field in the document for spatial search. And this issue is happening while doing a geospatial query,

```
$geo = $helper->geofilt('location', $userLat, $userLon, $searchRadius);
$query->createFilterQuery('location')->setQuery($geo);
```

`location_0_coordinate` is a dynamic field generated by solr and I am not doing anything with this. I've deleted all the documents and re-indexed the core (there are not too many documents) which seems to solve this issue for some time until it pops up again. Any idea why it is happening?

Here is the full stack trace

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: unexpected docvalues type NONE for field 'location_0_coordinate' (expected one of [BINARY, NUMERIC, SORTED, SORTED_NUMERIC, SORTED_SET]). Re-index with correct docvalues type.
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DocValues.checkField(DocValues.java:212)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DocValues.getDocsWithField(DocValues.java:324)
    at org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher.decorateDocValueFields(SolrIndexSearcher.java:783)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.RealTimeGetComponent.getInputDocument(RealTimeGetComponent.java:351)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.getUpdatedDocument(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:1130)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.versionAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:1042)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.processAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:736)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessorFactory$LogUpdateProcessor.processAdd(LogUpdateProcessorFactory.java:103)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:48)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.AddSchemaFieldsUpdateProcessorFactory$AddSchemaFieldsUpdateProcessor.processAdd(AddSchemaFieldsUpdateProcessorFactory.java:336)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:48)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.processAdd(FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.java:118)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:48)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.processAdd(FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.java:118)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:48)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.processAdd(FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.java:118)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:48)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.processAdd(FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.java:118)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:48)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.FieldNameMutatingUpdateProcessorFactory$1.processAdd(FieldNameMutatingUpdateProcessorFactory.java:74)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:48)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.processAdd(FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.java:118)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:48)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.AbstractDefaultValueUpdateProcessorFactory$DefaultValueUpdateProcessor.processAdd(AbstractDefaultValueUpdateProcessorFactory.java:91)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.XMLLoader.processUpdate(XMLLoader.java:250)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.XMLLoader.load(XMLLoader.java:177)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.UpdateRequestHandler$1.load(UpdateRequestHandler.java:97)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:68)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:166)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:2306)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.execute(HttpSolrCall.java:658)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:464)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:345)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:296)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1691)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:582)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1180)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:512)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1112)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:534)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:320)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:303)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Could it be that you've indexed a document with an empty location (i.e. still provided a field, but with a missing value)?

Comment: @MatsLindh I tried checking this. from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238609/how-to-query-solr-for-empty-fields but its returning all the docs and it has value in location. though i have not checked for all the documents, but first 10 documents have location value.

Comment: could you go over this link If this could help http://makble.com/lucene-sort-unexpected-docvalues-type-none-for-field-date

Answer (score 1):

In Lucene 5, the sorting field use a very different kind of field. A simple not analyzed stored field is not enough. Instead you need to add the field with the type SortedDocValuesField.

According to SortedDocValuesField . You need add a StoredField with the same field name if you want to get the value from matched document.

For E.g.:

```
doc.add(new SortedDocValuesField ("date", new BytesRef(date) ));
doc.add(new StoredField("date", date));
```

Answer (score -1):

You basically just need to reset your index. Most likely remove the data folder and restart solr.
What happened was you had some data indexed in there, and then changed (updated) that field name or the schema.xml.

Upon a reload